# Why can I not remove items from a tuple like I can from a list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I generated a list of numbers through the creation of permutations.  I'm now trying to remove the non-prime numbers from this list.

```
import itertools
from sympy import isprime

values = list(itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))

def removeNonPrimes(items):
    return [p for p in items if isprime(p)]

primes = removeNonPrimes(values)       
print primes
```

However, when I try to create a new list with only the prime numbers, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Why is this a tuple and not a list?  Still, why can I not remove items from a tuple like I can a list?

Comment: `values` is a list that contains `tuple` objects, that will look like `(0, 1, 2, 3)`. That is the `p` you pass to `isprime(p)`, which is what is raising the error. I don't use `sympy` so I can only speculate, but likely, `isprime` expects an *integer* not a tuple, because whatever you pass to `isprime` is calling `int(...)` on `p`

Comment: You're not generating a list of numbers. You're generating a list of tuples of numbers. `(5, 4, 7, 1)` is not `5471`.

Comment: You should print(values) to see where it gets wrong.

Comment: This reads as [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344593). What is your end goal? All primes from 0-1000 with non-repeating digits (including leading zeroes)?

Comment: In this case, my end goal was to get the answers to the questions I asked.  I don't want anyone to solve this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, tuples are immutable. You can convert to a list, remove stuff, and then convert back to tuple if you need. Also, "values" is a list, but it's a list of tuples. Easy way to convert to list of lists:

```
values=[list(x) for x in values]
```

Comment: This addresses the question in the subject line, not the problem the OP is having...

Comment: This almost *certainly* won't fix the underlying problem. Rather, the error will now be `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: Well, that is the question he asked. If he edits the question, I'm happy to update.

Comment: It may be worth referring to [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344593): his actual issue has nothing to do with removing items, from lists or tuples. your answer is irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: I now understand the issue, and I'll work with "values" to make it into a list of integers for this particular issue.  I also understand tuples are immutable now.  I don't appreciate the negative score on my question - I still believe it was a valid question that I wanted answered which will affect whether I choose to use tuples going forward in my code.